# PROC IML Log (SAS Studio)

Tags: sas, sas-studio

I am relatively new to PROC IML procedure. I'd like to have my log to be completely clean, which includes log showing no notes and  "!"(length in this case too?) if possible. How can I eliminate the note, keep my CPU and performance very efficient?

Thank you for your help!! I appreciate it!.- Michelle

```
 71         proc iml;
 NOTE: IML Ready
 72         
 72       !  varNames={"NACCZMMS" "NACCZLMI" "NACCZLMD" "NACCZDFT" "NACCAGEB"};
 73         
 73       !  use Class2.exercise2;
 NOTE: Data file CLASS2.EXERCISE2.DATA is in a format that is native to 
another host, or the file encoding does not 
   match the session encoding. Cross Environment Data Access will be used, 
which might require additional CPU 
   resources and might reduce performance.
 74         
 74       !  read all var varNames into CG;
 75         
 75       !  print CG[c=varNames];
 75       !                        /*c for colname*/
 76         quit;
```

Comment: That message has nothing to do with IML.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can convert the data set to a format that's optimal for your system.

   ```
   data exercise2;
   set class.exercise2;
   run;
   ```

Then use the exercise2 data in your IML code. You only need to do this once. This has to do with the fact that the data set was created on a different operating system than yours and SAS is letting you know that. It will do the conversion automatically, but can slow things down.

2. Turn on the `option NONOTES;` which will suppress all NOTES to the LOG. But WARNINGS will be displayed. I don't recommend this as NOTES can be very useful to detect issues in your code.

Comment: Thank you Reeza! This is very helpful. I am glad I learned this today.